# How to make a menu appear (from the left) and disappear on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a button and a listview menu and I want it to toggle from left to right below the button on button click - it should appear and disappear. Please help. Thank you.

```
$('#menu').click(function () {
    if ($('#pageone').is(':visible')){
        $('#pageone').fadeOut();
    } else {
        $('#pageone').toggle('slide', {
            direction: 'left'
        }, 1000, function(){ 
            $('#pageone').fadeIn();
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Typo: you're missing a closing `'` on the `#menu` selector. I would suggest you use an editor with syntax highlighting which makes it impossible to miss errors like this.

Comment: can you make jsfiddle ????

Comment: Post the corresponding html within your question, also clearly explain what is going wrong.

Comment: [Rory](http://stackoverflow.com/users/519413/rory-mccrossan) - Hi Rory - It doesn't work even with the quote - and thanks for your suggestion - it does help with brackets also

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zfh3Lphg/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var isOpen =true;
function toggleMenu(){
 
  if(isOpen){
    $('#pageone').hide('slow');
    isOpen = false;
    }else{
       $('#pageone').show('slow');
       isOpen = true;
      }
    
    
}
```

```css
#top
{
  clear:both;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  height:40%;
  width:100%;
  background-color:#DCDCDC;
  text-align:center;
}
#bottom
{
   clear:both;
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0;
   height:60%;
   width:100%;
   background-color:#ffc878;
   text-align:center;
}
#menu
{
   position:fixed;
   left:2%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top">
    <h2>Knowledge Point</h2>
    <h2>Self Test</h2>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    <button id="menu" onclick="toggleMenu()">☰</button>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
<div data-role="page" id="pageone" style="float:left;width :30%;">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
      <li data-icon="plus"><a href="question.html">Add a new question</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div> 
<div id="question" style="float:right; width:70%;">
Testing Content
<br>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This shouldve been a comment asking if OP is looking for a left menu.

Comment: Without source code we can't say anything, so this may be right option for him.

Comment: Keyword is MAY. Don't forget other users might also look at this question in the future. Answers are supposed to clearly give a direct answer to the question asked, not give pointers, possible solutions or opinions. If you're not sure about what the OP wants, or you need stuff like source code, be like the rest of us and ask for a clearer question. This only confuses people that do not yet understand what this question (or your answer) is about.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have changed my answer.